# Impossible to find the function setBackground on a object

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do something like: If the column E has the word ok, column D gets formated as red. Seens preety easy, but something is wrong as I'm not entenring the if. Do u guys know what is wrong? I have read some other topics, but seens preety much the same

```
function onEdit() {

var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var myRangeValues = ss.getRange('D7:E').getValues();

Browser.msgBox(myRangeValues);
for (var i = 0; i < myRangeValues.length; i++){
 if(myRangeValues[i][0] == 'ok'){ 
   myRangeValues[i][0].setBackground('red');

 }
} 
}
```

Thanks for the attention.

**EDIT:** 
*new code not working*. I tried to put the logger.log in other lines as well. even without the logger, the error I get is that the function setBackground is impossible to find in the object.

```
function onEdit() {

var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var myRangeValues = ss.getRange('D7:E').getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < myRangeValues.length; i++) 
{
 if(myRangeValues[i][1] == 'ok')
 { 
  myRangeValues[i][0].setBackground('red');
  //Logger.log("myRangeValues[i][1]: " + myRangeValues[i][1]);

 }
}

}
```

Comment: Can't get it done. Tried another ways but all of then result in the same way of not finding the function setBackground or setBackgroundColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up methods.
value arrays don't have `setBackground()` method, this is a [spreadsheet range method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String))

use the code below to do what you want :

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var myRangeValues = ss.getRange('D7:E').getValues();
  var myRangeColors = ss.getRange('D7:E').getBackgrounds();// get the colors
  for (var i = 0; i < myRangeValues.length; i++) 
  {
    if(myRangeValues[i][1] == 'ok')
    { 
      myRangeColors[i][0]='#F00';
    }
  }
  ss.getRange('D7:E').setBackgrounds(myRangeColors); //set the modified colors
}
```